Does ForAll() evaluate the iteration all at once or based on a sequence
I have a problem understanding how the ForAll() works internally inside power apps which is connected to sharepoint, based on the documentation it will execute all the formulas at once, but based on my test it will do this based on a sequence one by one. for example i have this formula which do these steps:-
ClearCollect(colTeamSitesItem,Filter('Team Sites',1=1));
ClearCollect(colAllGroups,Office365Groups.ListGroups().value);
ForAll(colAllGroups As group,
ForAll(colTeamSitesItem As i2,

If(Lower(group.displayName)=Lower(i2.'Team Site Name'),
Collect(colRelatedGroupsIds,group.id))));

ForAll(colRelatedGroupsIds As group,
Collect(colRelatedPlanners,
Planner.ListGroupPlans(group.Value).value);

ForAll(colRelatedPlanners As planner,
Collect(colRelatedPlannerTasks,
Planner.ListTasksV3(planner.id,group.Value).value);
ForAll(colRelatedPlannerTasks As task,
ForAll(task._assignments As taskAssignment,
Patch(finalResult,Defaults(finalResult),
{
PlanTitle:planner.title,
AssignedToUserId:taskAssignment.userId,
Status:task.percentComplete,
TaskTitle:task.title,
DueDate:task.dueDateTime
})
));
RemoveIf(colRelatedPlannerTasks,true));
RemoveIf(colRelatedPlanners,true));


Get the Office 365 groups from a sharepoint list

Get All the Office 365 groups from AD

check if the AD group is define inside the sharepoint group and build the colRelatedGroupsIds

iterate over the colRelatedGroupsIds >> and for each group get the group plans + iterate over the Plan Tasks

after iterating over each plan + each group i Clear the related collection, to avoid duplicate and wrong Plan Tasks.


now my above code is working well.. but it could not work well, unless the ForAll() execute the formulas in a sequence and not all at once.. but based on my reading is that ForAll() does not execute the formulas in a sequence but rather all at once.. so can anyone advice how ForAll() works internally?
Thanks

Anecdotally, my experience is the same as yours. It appears to process in a sequence. However, I have just read that it tries to do things in parallel if it can...

When writing your formula, keep in mind that records can be processed
in any order and, when possible, in parallel.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/author-advanced-formulas-powerapps/4-forall-function#:~:text=When%20writing%20your%20formula%2C%20keep%20in%20mind%20that%20records%20can%20be%20processed%20in%20any%20order%20and%2C%20when%20possible%2C%20in%20parallel.

thanks for the reply.. so is there a way to force forall to run in sequential order ?
